# Heat Map of ConvNext pretrained

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have trained a dataset on ConvNext Small. I want to generate heatmap of misclassified images. 1st image of class 0 is classified as image of class24. I am trying to generate its heat map using GradCam but getting message no attribute is generated

def generate_and_overlay_heatmap_for_first_misclassified_image(misclassified_info, model):
for info in misclassified_info:
image_name = info['image_name']
true_label = info['true_label']

```
    # Load and preprocess the image
    image_path = os.path.join('I:\\K_Folds\\PlantDoc\\Fold1\\Testing\\AP_C', image_name)
    image = Image.open(image_path)
  #  input_image = heatmap_transform(image)
  #  input_image = input_image.unsqueeze(0).to(device)

    input_image = heatmap_transform(image)
    input_image = input_image.unsqueeze(0).to(device)
    print("Input Image Shape:", input_image.shape)

    # After defining true_label
    true_label = info['true_label']
    print("True Label:", true_label)
    # After defining attributions
    # Create a Guided Grad-CAM attribute method (adjust layer based on your model architecture)
    guided_grad_cam = GuidedGradCam(model, model.norm)  # You can adjust the layer based on your model architecture

    # Get the heatmap attribute using Guided Grad-CAM
    attributions = guided_grad_cam.attribute(input_image, target=true_label)

    print("Attributions Shape:", attributions.shape)


    # Check if attributions tensor is empty
    if attributions.size(0) == 0:
        print(f"No attributions generated for {image_name}")
        break  # Stop processing if no attributions were generated

    # Convert the attributions to a grayscale heatmap
    heatmap = viz.visualize_image_attr(attributions[0].cpu().numpy(),
                                       original_image=input_image[0].cpu().numpy(),
                                       method="heat_map")

    # Overlay the heatmap on the original image
    heatmap_overlay = cv2.addWeighted(np.array(image), 0.7, heatmap, 0.3, 0)

    # Display the original image and the heatmap overlay
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title('Original Image')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(heatmap_overlay)
    plt.title('Heatmap Overlay')

    plt.show()

    # Exit the loop after processing the first misclassified image
    break
```

## Generate and overlay heatmap for the first misclassified image

generate_and_overlay_heatmap_for_first_misclassified_image(misclassified_info, model)

Comment: Always include full error messages verbatim, not your interpretation of it.